# Multiple update Panel in Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery, updatepanel

I am new Asp.net and working on project, where I have to ajaxify the basic asp.net

I have master page and content page. Master page has menu and buttons. The content page have various fieldsets as below.

1. Update Record Fieldset
2. Add  Record Fieldset
3. Query and Grid.

updatepanel id=UpdatePanelOuter runat=server UpdateMode=Conditional> Likewise for all the nested UpdatePanels. The Scriptmanager is in Masterpage with EnablePartialRendering=true

What I have in code behind is ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(AddUpdatePanel) In button click event function AddUpdatePanel.Update() .

When the content page is loaded, I have the queryform and DataGrid. There are couple grid command like view, update and delete.

When I click update command from the grid, I am making `UpdateFieldset.visible=true`  and `QueryGridField.visible=false`.

On submit button, its stored the data , give the message and go back to original contentpage with `querygridFieldset.visible =true`.

Question: What I am trying and have not been successfull is

1. when I click on the buttons, my datetime , menus in the master page
   must not  be refreshed.
2. On click in the Update button, only that particular Fieldset should
   be sent to the server.

At the same time, I have updated by Web.config and there is no compilation error

---

## Master Page: Menu, Current System Date time, Login Name, Buttons

Content Page: ContentPlaceHolder1 UpdateRecordFieldset AddRecordFieldset QueryandGridFieldset

Comment: PLease add some code what you have tried/done

Comment: <asp:updatepanel id="UpdatePanelOuter" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> <contenttemplate>   Likewise for all the nested UpdatePanel.   The Scriptmanager is in Masterpage with EnablePartialRendering="true".  //ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(AddUpdatePanel);

Comment: updatepanel id=UpdatePanelOuter runat=server UpdateMode=Conditional> 
Likewise for all the nested UpdatePanel. The Scriptmanager is in Masterpage with EnablePartialRendering=true
ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(AddUpdatePanel) 

void Btn_noSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
AddUpdatePanel.Update()
}

Comment: PLease add these codes in question ask question to the point

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what excalty is your requirement but if you have multiple update panels and master page and content page structure.

Please check the script manager and update panel properties according to this link:

http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/updatepaneloverview.aspx

`"Using UpdatePanel Controls in Master Pages"` & `"Using Nested UpdatePanel Controls"` are titles in same link.

Hope this help.

Comment: I went through the link and did the same separately and it worked.  DO I have a create a new page (ajax based) and copyt he sources for it work?

Comment: No need to do that just try to implement simillar properties for `update panel` and `script manager` in your aspx page.